# How to transfer .gcda file content into another file?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, embedded, gcov

I have modified the source code of `gcov` library to integrate it for my embedded target. I changed the parts where `gcov` opens `.gcda` file and writes the collected data into this file. In my modified case, it writes collected data into a buffer which I send through a network socket. In my client part of the network, I can successfully take the data. I cross checked the sizes that I transferred through network and the size of actual data collected with an unmodified `libgcov`, they match!

My problem is to open `.gcda` file in the client part and writing the data in my buffer to `.gcda` file. In `fwrite(readBuf,sizeof(char),256,file)` I do not know what will be the size of the data that I transferred. Is `.gcda` file transfers a binary data, or something else?

Comment: Write the actual size of the data instead of a fixed size. If you don't know the expected size then you might have to change your network protocol to transmit the size information in some way.

Comment: When you broke the lib at the point where it woudl open/write to the file, and just transfer as binary, open your local file in binary mode. You should actually use the return value of your `read() /recv()` function. It returns the number of bytes read or 0 at the end. Per default, `read() / recv()` would block until something is available. Then you just write the number of bytes received into your file. `ssize_t ret; gcdafd= open(filename, "ab+"); while((ret = read(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) { write(gcdafd, buf, ret); }`